# Insert query vs select query performance mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have executed an insert query as follows -
**Insert into tablename

select
query1 union query2**

Now if I execute the select part of this insert query,it takes around 2-3 minutes.However,the entire insert script is taking more than 8 minutes.As per my knowledge the insert and corresponding select queries should take almost the same time for execution.

So is their any other factor that could impact the execution time of the insert?

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct that insert and corresponding select takes the same time, it should not!
The select query just "reads" data and transmit them; if you are trying the query in an application (like phpMyadmin) is very likely to limit query result to paginate them, so the select is faster (as it doesn't select all the data).
The insert query must read that data, insert in the table, update primary key tree, update every other index on that table, update every view using that table, triggering any trigger on that table/column, ecc... so the insert operates a LOT way more actions than an insert.
So IT'S normal that the insert is slower than the select, how much slower depends on your tables and db structure.
You could optimize the insert with some db specific options, for example you could read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) for mysql, if you are on DB2 you could crete a temp file then cpyf that into the real one, and so on...

Comment: Agreed.
The complexity of the query is as follows :  

2 SUBQUERIES
3 Joins
3 Tables

Comment: Agreed.
The complexity of the query is as follows :  

2 SUBQUERIES
3 Joins
3 Tables

Earlier we were using the same insert query so the the execution time was 3-4 minutes.However,now this query is taking more than 10 minutes to execute.
We are getting the following thread state after executing this query:

Query End

How to resolve this issue?